# All values getting upadted when tried to update single element in an associative array in Vue 3

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

I have the below code in Vue3:

```js
    data: function() {
        return {
            testData:[],
        }
    },

    mounted() {
        var testObj = {
            name: 'aniket',
            lastname: 'mahadik'
        }

        for (let index = 0; index < 3; index++) {
            this.testData.push(testObj);
        }
    },

    methods: {
        updateLastName: function(key) {
            this.testData[key].lastname = 'kirve';
        }
    }
```

When I call `updateLastName(1)` to update the `lastname` of only the second element, it's updating the `lastname` of all the elements.

I tried several ways but found no desired result.

Can someone point out to me what is going wrong here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is because you are pushing the reference to the same object in the array so when you update any item in the array you are instead updating every item since it reference the same object.

Either push by cloning the object :
`testData.value.push({...testObj})`

Or put the definition in the push

`testData.value.push({ name: 'aniket', lastname: 'mahadik' })`

[Is JavaScript a pass-by-reference or pass-by-value language?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/518000/is-javascript-a-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value-language)

Comment: Thanks Pierre for the knowledge. It worked.